# Prevent glue to read all files from S3 folder

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

We have one S3 folder that is being used for storing different files for ETL processing separately. The ETL processing of one files is reading all other files placed in the same S3 folder. I don't see an option to read only file from the folder. The Location property in the table is set to the folder level.

Code:

```
gluedb = "srcgluedb"
gluetbl = "gluesrctable" 
dfRead=glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=gluedb, table_name=gluetbl) 
df = dfRead.toDF()
```

Comment: Please add some code that shows how you're reading from S3.

Comment: Here is the code
gluedb = "srcgluedb"
gluetbl = "gluesrctable"

dfRead = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=gluedb, table_name=gluetbl)
df = dfRead.toDF()

the glue table is reading two files from S3 bucket placed in the same folder. The two files have different name and structure. I suspect some issue with the glue table setup , but I don't see an option to read a particular file from the source vs reading all file placed at that location.

Comment: Can you check the tabledefinition for the location of the data?

Comment: You don't have any choice about the structure of the table, so there's nothing you can do to narrow down the contents of the table. If your job has direct access to the S3 bucket, you can read from a specific S3 object with something like `glueContext.spark_session.csv(path="s3://bucketname/this/is/the/key.csv")`. Of course you'll need to use the correct read method for whatever format is appropriate for the S3 object.

Comment: @RobertKossendey I created the table defination manually as i know the file structure to read and it doesn't give an option to read a particular file. It only give option to provide a file path. Hence it reads all the files located in that path.

Comment: @jscott Will try that option.